# True or False question for Fubini's Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

a) Is it true that $$\iint_{R} f(x,y)dydx=\iint_{R} f(x,y)dxdy$$

I thought this would be true because of Fubini's Theorem however Fubini's Theorem requires $f(x,y)$ to be continuous on $R$. There is no such condition in this problem. Therefore it is false?

b) If $R$ is the rectangle $0\leq x\leq a, 0\leq y\leq b$ and $S$ is the rectangle $-a\leq x\leq 0, -b \leq y\leq 0$ then

$$\iint_{R} f(x,y)dA=-\iint_{S} f(x,y) dA$$

I think this is false and the counter example I would use is

$f(x,y)=1$

Then $\int_{0}^{b}\int_{0}^{a} dydx = \int_{-b}^{0}\int_{-a}^{0}dydx$

Is this correct?

Comment: There is no continuity in Fubini's Theorem. Where did you read  Fubini's Theorem from?

Comment: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/IteratedIntegrals.aspx

Comment: So is the answer then true?

Comment: Well, the result is true without continuity but I can prove it only using Measure Theory.

Comment: hmmm but I am in a vector calculus course, I have not learned any measure theory. So is the answer true for me?

Comment: In the link that I posted, it says that $f(x,y)$ needs to be continuous, but that is only over a rectangle. Is that why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a) Is it true that $$\iint_{R} f(x,y)dydx=\iint_{R} f(x,y)dxdy$$
>
> I thought this would be true because of Fubini's Theorem however
> Fubini's Theorem requires $f(x,y)$ to be continuous on $R$.

The continuity version of Fubini's Theorem in $\mathbb R^2$ is a special case.

The above equality does hold as long as $\int f(x,y)\,\mathrm dx$ and $\int f(x,y)\,\mathrm dy$ both exist on rectangle $R$'s respective edges.

> b) If $R$ is the rectangle $0\leq x\leq a, 0\leq y\leq b$ and $S$ is
> the rectangle $-a\leq x\leq 0, -b \leq y\leq 0$ then
>
> $$\iint_{R} f(x,y)dA=-\iint_{S} f(x,y) dA$$
>
> I think this is false and the counter example I would use is
>
> $\int_{0}^{b}\int_{0}^{a} dydx = \int_{-b}^{0}\int_{-a}^{0}dydx$
>
> Is this correct?

Yes (ignoring your typo where you interchanged $x$ and $y).$